# Why Terminal stop responding to Enter command and what I write?

Tags: common-lisp, clisp

I have a list of lists "straight":

```
(setq straight '(
        ("Arad"             366)
        ("Bucharest"          0)
        ("Craiova"          160)
        ("Dobreta"          242)
        ("Eforie"           161)
        ("Fagaras"          176)
        ("Giurgiu"           77)
        ("Hirsova"          151)    
        ("Iasi"             226)
        ("Lugoj"            244)
        ("Mehadia"          241)
        ("Neamt"            234)
        ("Oradea"           380)
        ("Pitesti"          100)
        ("Rimnicu Vilcea"   193)
        ("Sibiu"            253)
        ("Timisoara"        329)
        ("Urziceni"          80)
        ("Vaslui"           199)
        ("Zerind"           374)))
```

And I have a list `("Pitesti" 101)`. I'm trying to search through "straight" and find value corresponding to "Pitesti". However when I run my function, terminal stops responding to enter command and doesn't respond to anything I write. Here's the function:

```
(defun her (node)
  (setq s straight)
  (setq c '())
  (loop while (not (eq (car node)
                       (caar s)))
        do (setq s (cdr s)))
  (setq c (append node (car (cdar s)))))
```

Comment: Since it looks like an endless loop, you might want to stop it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your immediate problem: `eq` means object identity.  I guess that you give a singleton list of the city name to this function, so when you compare `(eq (car node) (caar s))`, you compare two strings.  As long as those two strings are not the same object (this might happen if they are both read as a literal from the same compilation—which seems quite unlikely here), this will be false.  Instead, you should use `string=`.

Since your comparisons never return true, that loop will keep on setting `s` to the tails of `straight`, but note that the `cdr` of `nil` is `nil` again: this will never terminate.

So, replacing `eq` with `string=` might solve your immediate problem.  However, there are more issues.

What happens if the string you pass doesn't actually exist in `straight`?  Then again, it will never terminate.  A better way to do this loop:

```
(loop :for pair :in straight
      :when (string= (car node) (car pair))
        :do (return pair))
```

The `for`-`in` construct will terminate at the end of the list, so you will get back `nil` if the string is missing.  `Loop` has another construct to find something: `thereis`:

```
(loop :for pair :in straight
      :thereis (when (string= (car node) (car pair)) pair))
```

Speaking of finding, why not use `find` instead of `loop`:

```
(find (car node) straight
      :test #'string=
      :key #'first)
```

Since using a list of lists for a simple associative structure is rather common (“association list” or “alist”), there is a specialized form for this:

```
(assoc (car node) straight
       :test #'string=)
```

Finally, a glaring general issue: you are `setq`ing free (most likely unbound) variables throughout.  Don't do that.  Strive to write referentially transparent functions.  Establish local bindings with `let` etc.  When you have a result, simply return it, don't set some global variable to it.